# .MOV uploads work from iPad but don't from chrome

Tags: html, ios

I am trying to upload .mov files that have been recorded using an iPad but I want to upload them using Chrome on the PC.

The video uploads just fine however on playback all I get is a white screen ( Audio + Play controls also load up fine ).

Alternatively when the video file is uploaded using an iPad and loaded on the PC (chrome again) , the video plays back as intended.

Im using a HTML5 video tag.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="files/nameremoved.mov" type="video/mp4">

 Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
```

My assumption is that iPad uploads compress the video into something that chrome can playback.

To fix this do I need to convert the .mov uploads that are uploaded using a PC to a chrome friendly format?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, what you would want to do is to upload them as mp4.
There's not supposed native .MOV support on chrome but you can try to add some extension.

Besides you are requesting chrome to play a type="video/mp4" and you are giving it a .mov

```
  <source src="files/nameremoved.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: Giving the video a 'video/mov' type results in the video not loading at all ( not even the audio ). If there is no native support of .mov files then what does IOS do to the .mov to make it compatible? I ask this because the ipad uploaded files are still .mov files .

Comment: MOV is very similar to MP4, you might be able to just change the extension and have it work. Perhaps IOS compress when you share a movie as low, medium or high quality